# Keep column and row order when storing pandas dataframe in json

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When storing data in a json object with to_json, and reading it back with read_json, rows and columns are returned sorted alphabetically. Is there a way to keep the results ordered or reorder them upon retrieval?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could use `orient='split'`, which stores the index and column information in lists, which preserve order:

```
In [34]: df
Out[34]: 
   A  C  B
5  0  1  2
4  3  4  5
3  6  7  8

In [35]: df.to_json(orient='split')
Out[35]: '{"columns":["A","C","B"],"index":[5,4,3],"data":[[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]]}'

In [36]: pd.read_json(df.to_json(orient='split'), orient='split')
Out[36]: 
   A  C  B
5  0  1  2
4  3  4  5
3  6  7  8
```

Just remember to use `orient='split'` on reading as well, or you'll get

```
In [37]: pd.read_json(df.to_json(orient='split'))
Out[37]: 
  columns       data  index
0       A  [0, 1, 2]      5
1       C  [3, 4, 5]      4
2       B  [6, 7, 8]      3
```

Comment: i have a bunch of dates, thats getting converted to epoch timestamps whereas the original format is YYYY-MM-DD. How can i retain the order, and date formats?

Comment: @Naveen, you need manually to set _dtypes_ after `read_json()`, like this `df['date_operation'] = df['date_operation'].astype('datetime64[ms]') . This convert default milliseconds produced by `df.to_json()`

Comment: Is the written json index order `json.loads(df.to_json(orient='split'))['index']` **guaranteed** to be identical to the original index `df.index.to_list()` ???
It's not written in the documentation as I can see.
That would save us from deserializing to get the index.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a format with "orient='records'" and keep orders of the column, try to make a function like this. I don't think it is a wise approach, and do not recommend because it does not guarantee its order.

```
def df_to_json(df):
    res_arr = []
    ldf = df.copy()
    ldf=ldf.fillna('')
    lcolumns = [ldf.index.name] + list(ldf.columns)
    for key, value in ldf.iterrows():
        lvalues = [key] + list(value)
        res_arr.append(dict(zip(lcolumns, lvalues)))
    return json.dumps(res_arr)
```

In addition, for reading without sorted column please ref this [link] ([Python json.loads changes the order of the object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43789439/python-json-loads-changes-the-order-of-the-object))

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

lets say you have a pandas dataframe, that you read

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json ('/abc.json')
df.head()
```

that give following
[image]

now there are two ways to save to json using pandas to_json
result.sample(200).to_json('abc_sample.json',orient='split')
that will give the order like this one column
[image]

> **however, to preserve the order like in csv, use this one**

```
result.sample(200).to_json('abc_sample_2nd.json',orient='records')
```

this will give result as
[image]