# Python json.loads changes the order of the object

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I've got a file that contains a JSON object. It's been loaded the following way:

```
with open('data.json', 'r') as input_file:
  input_data = input_file.read()
```

At this point input_data contains just a string, and now I proceed to parse it into JSON:

```
data_content = json.loads(input_data.decode('utf-8'))
```

data_content has the JSON representation of the string which is what I need, but for some reason not clear to me after json.loads it is altering the order original order of the keys, so for instance, if my file contained something like:

```
{ "z_id": 312312,
  "fname": "test",
  "program": "none",
  "org": null
}
```

After json.loads the order is altered to let's say something like:

```
{ "fname": "test",
  "program": None,
  "z_id": 312312,
  "org": "none"
}
```

Why is this happening? Is there a way to preserve the order? I'm using Python 2.7.

Comment: why do you need dictionary order?

Comment: If you really need order, then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921699/can-i-get-json-to-load-into-an-ordereddict-in-python

Comment: I believe this was a bad example because the keys are ordered alphabetically. I'll edit the example. My point is that I want the object not altered but to hold whatever order it had initially

Comment: If you need order, then use Python3.6: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39980323/7216865

Comment: **See also:**  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921699

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Dictionaries (objects) in python have no guaranteed order.  So when parsed into a `dict`, the order is lost.

If the order is important for some reason, you can have `json.loads` use an `OrderedDict` instead, which is like a `dict`, but the order of keys is saved.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

data_content = json.loads(input_data.decode('utf-8'), object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
```

Comment: [Since Python 3.7 `json.loads` preserves dict order by default.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921699/can-i-get-json-to-load-into-an-ordereddict)

Answer (score 3):

This is not an issue with json.load.  Dictionaries in Python are not order enforced, so you will get it out of order; generally speaking, it doesn't matter, because you access elements based on strings, like `"id"`.

Comment: It does matter in this case since I gotta dump the data into an excel file and need preserve the structure. All my files will not have the same structure so cannot access each element individually