# How to append element at the end in json file using python?

Tags: python, json

I have hundreds of thousands of json files with annotations info in them.
Example json file:

```
{
  "version": "4.5.4",
  "flags": {
    "flag1": false,
    "surface": false,
    "gtype": false,
    "light": false
  },
  "shapes": [
    {
      "label": "object-1",
      "points": [
        [
          100.5,
          105.65423
        ]
      ],
      "group_id": null,
      "shape_type": "point",
      "flags": {}
    },
    {
      "label": "assembly",
      "points": [
        [
          31.8416,
          52.546
        ],
        [
          65,
          97
        ]
      ],
      "group_id": null,
      "shape_type": "rectangle",
      "flags": {}
    }
  ],
  "location": "/data/abc.bmp",
  "Data": null,
  "Height": 540,
  "Width": 960
}
```

I want to add element at the end of json file. say, element name is path and it is a string, then my desired output should look like,

```
... existing data in json ...
... existing data in json ...

  "location": "/data/abc.bmp",
  "Data": null,
  "Height": 540,
  "Width": 960,
  "path": "/data/pqr.pgm"
}
```

I have python code which does add element to the json file, but it re-arranges contents of file.
Following is how my code reads json

```
with open(jsonFileName,"r") as jsonFile:
            jsonData = json.loads(jsonFile.read())
```

And following is how I am adding new element to the file

```
jsonData['path'] = pathValueString
with open(jsonFileName, "w") as outputJsonFile:                    
    outputJsonFile.seek(0,2)
    json.dump(jsonData, outputJsonFile, indent=4)
```

Python version : 3.4.10

Comment: Update your Python to at least 3.7+ and watch the magic happen.

Comment: If you are forced to use 3.4, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43789439/python-json-loads-changes-the-order-of-the-object

But JSON defines objects as an unordered collection, so your file is still valid.

Comment: I dont have to be strict about python version. I am using Python3.8 now, and I dont see the issue anymore!
I really appreciate quick response! Thank you so much! @matszwecja

Comment: @AkshayMoharir posted as an answer in case you want to accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Up to Python 3.6, standard `dict`s were unordered, meaning there was no guarantee that when json was loaded and saved order of keys would remain the same. There was possibility of using `from collections import OrderedDict` but of course making it work for `json.loads` wasn't trivial.

Since 3.7, `dict` objects are guaranteed to keep insertion order, so you can use it to keep the order as in the original file.